# Opencart 2.x - show featured module if category is empty

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

I wish to show a module (e.g.: Featured Products) in an empty category page (a category with no products available).

I've been looking for a solution (with PHP or an extension/mod), with no success.
Thanks.

Comment: is your question about how to do such a thing manually (with code) ?

Comment: @AbdoAdel yes! I'm a PHP programmer. If exists an extension or mod to do this, will be appreciate.
If not, the way to get there is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If exists an extension or mod to do this

I never heard of such an extension and I don't think that there extensions of this type (anyway, have a look at the [extensions store](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension))

#### If not, the way to get there is enough

**Basically we will work with two files:**
Category controller file:`<OC_ROOT>/catalog/controller/product/category.php`
Category view file:`<OC_ROOT>/catalog/view/theme/xxx/template/product/category.tpl`

***We just need to:***

***(1) Determine to load the module or not (In the controller)***
Using a simple if statement, you can check if the # of products in the current category equals zero, then you can proceed with constructing the module, luckily we already have the # of products in that line:
`$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);`
so you just need to check if `$product_total == 0`

***(2) Construct the module HTML in a proper way (In the controller)***
If you opened any controller, you will notice that there is a line always used to execute some controller and return it's output as a string, this line is:
`$this->load->controller('controller route')`
you can even notice it in the same file:
`$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');`

so you just need to copy that line and use it to load the module that you want (using the module route which is `module/featured` for your case), however, some modules in OC expect some parameters to be passed to the `index()` function and won't work without it, don't panic :D, you just need to open any file that makes use of modules (such as `common/column_left.php`) and do the same, I copied it for you (with slight modification):

```php
if ($this->config->get($module_code . '_status')) 
{
  $data['module_html'] = $this->load->controller('module/' . $module_code);
}
else
{
  $this->load->model('extension/module');
  $setting_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($module_id);
  if ($setting_info) 
  {
    $data['module_html'] = $this->load->controller('module/' . $module_code, $setting_info);
  }
}
```

the values of `$module_id` and `$module_code` can be found in the table `<DB_PREFIX>_module`, for your case they will be:

```php
$module_id = 28;
$module_code = 'featured';
```

***(3) Display the module in the page (In the view)***
Just check if the value of `$module_html` is set, then display it in the container div

---

*P.S: This [artice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru) is very good and provides an excellent base to develop code for open cart 1.5.x, it can also be used for OC 2.x with little modification, Good Luck!*